# How to validate an Oracle query string in C# code ?

Tags: c#, oracle

How I can validate an Oracle query that is syntactically correct or not in C# code. So far I have tried to find relevant solutions on Internet but couldn't find any. I am not sure how can I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for this purpose.

Comment: Fire the sql and see what it does? It´ll throw an exception if your query has whrong syntax. Anyway without any idea of what your query might look like and where it comes from we can´t even make a guess how to validate it.

Comment: Why do you want to validate it in the first place? Are you using "dynamic sql" queries by concatenating strings? No matter what validation you perfrom, you'll always be exposed to sql injection attacks or conversion problems. Use parameterized queries instead. And/or an ORM/microORM like EF, Dapper etc

Comment: @HimBromBeere, actually I want to validate the syntax of the query string before executing it to the server. The limitation in directly executing to the server that I could not be able to get all the error collectively.

Comment: @Panagiotis Actually, I am building that Oracle query and then executing it so there is no chancce of sql injection attacks. My code will not accept any type of sql string directly from the external sources. After generating that query string, I want to validate it's syntax whether it is correct or not. If not, it should give me all the errors.

Comment: @Anonymous that means there *is* a serious chance of injection and conversion problems. Otherwise you wouldn't have to validate anything. What query? What does it do? Does it use parameters or not? If not why?  Post the code. Validation isn't the answer

Comment: When the query isn´t built from a user-inout does it even *change*? If it doesn´t there´s no need to validate it again and again. Do it once (e.g. by firing the sql and see what heppens) and only once.

Comment: If you want to use different `WHERE` statements or `SELECT` fields, use an ORM like EF and LINQ and let *them* generate the SQL statement. You'll avoid any conversion issues and performance won't be affected. Or use a microORM like Dapper

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler only compiles c# code, not sql strings therefore C# cannot check if your SQL query is syntactically correct. You can only check it through some application that connects directly to oracle db(e.g Oracle SQL Developer, TOAD, SQLPlus etc.)

Comment: Yes C# cannot directly validate any query string, but we have different parser available as T100SqlParser for validating SQLServer query string. I am concerned about similar parser for Oracle query strings if there is any.

Comment: There is one parser that can be used in .NET to validate Oracle SQL query but i think its paid. Check this [link](http://www.sqlparser.com/download.php)